# Foundation-compatible jQuery carousel?

Tags: jquery, carousel, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation to create a website and have faced a problem. I want the home page to include a 930px-wide banner than flips the image that it displays. I have currently created a jQuery solution by, as I always have, floating the <li> elements that are displaying as blocks leftward and creating a fixed-width container "window" <div> around it.

The only problem is that this is not in any way compatible with Foundation's responsive CSS. What I would ideally like is every <li> to independently adjust according to Foundation's rules, similar to the banner here: http://www.salesforce.com/

Does anyone have any ideas? I have looked at Foundation's clearing libraries and the orbit libraries and none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you are looking for a way to show/hide elements depending on display size. [Zurb Foundation has a series of classes to augment this.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html)